# Why input normalization leads to worse performance?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, normalization

I'm building quite simple NN with Dense layers followed by ReLU activations and I noticed something unexpected. Generally, I've been confident that normalizing the input to have mean of 0 and standard deviation of 1 is always a good thing for linear models, including Neural Networks, as it usually stabilise the training. With my example though, it doesn't work at all - training with Keras Normalization layer included makes the validation error worse and network is training longer (it needs far more epochs to arrive remotely close to the best observed performance). I'm quite puzzled and haven't managed to explain the reason for this phenomenon. My network is defined as follows (simplified version):

```
class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__(dynamic=True)
    self.norm_layer = tf.keras.layers.Normalization(axis=-1)
        
    self.layer1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, 
                                        activation='relu', use_bias=True,
                                        kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.05, seed=None))
    self.layer2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, 
                                        activation='relu', 
                                        use_bias=True, 
                                        kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.05, seed=None))
    self.r1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, 
                                    activation=tf.exp, 
                                    use_bias=True, 
                                    kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean=-0.1, stddev=0.05, seed=None))

    
def call(self, inputs, training=False):
    if training:
        self.norm_layer.adapt(inputs)
    inputs = self.norm_layer(inputs)
            
    x = self.layer1(inputs)
    x = self.layer2(x)
    x = self.layer3(x)
    return x
```

While the distribution of input features looks as follows:
[image]
[image]

What is the possible explanation behind the failure of normalization layer? isn't standardising inputs always recommended preprocessing step?

Comment: Plot the distribution of the features for a handful of the features. That would be more useful than knowing their mean and std.

Comment: how many features fo you have? relu is not the best choice for "tight" layers, because the can lead to dead neurons... maybe try with different activation function that don't saturate (SeLU, Leaky ReLU etc)

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia I have 40 input features.

Comment: @Xaume try using non saturable activation functions, like Leaky resu and so on, or change the initialization of the relu weights (if you initialize the weight as a standard normal, and inputs are standard normal, you will have that many neurons has the preactivation t be negative, thus making the relu 0)

Comment: That makes total sense. Do you have an idea which initialization could work better?

Comment: Randomnormal is a good option: https://keras.io/api/layers/initializers/

Comment: I'm already doing RandomNormal, which might be the source of dead ReLU neurons as suggested by @AlbertoSinigaglia - that's why I was asking about an alternative.

Comment: depends on what framework you are using, for tf you have many examples https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/initializers ... however, maybe a linear layer at the beginning might still do the job, since til will map the value in the whole domain of relu, learning when it's needed to be 0 and when no (btw, relu are meant to be used in very wide layers, in order to avoid having too many dead neurons, what about using SeLu sa said before, to avoid this problem?)

Comment: Unfortunately SeLU leads to exploding gradient problem (the training starts just fine and the loss is decreasing but it reaches NaN values after a while), while LeakyReLU produces comparable performance